# Synchronizing Mobile Data (SQLite) with Server Data (Mysql) Horizontally (by row)

Tags: mysql, sqlite, synchronization

I am building a mobile application that I want the save data should be available across multiple devices for the login user only.

E.g If a user login to the mobile application, only his records (data) should be synchronized (available offline) maybe using the user unique id.

For security reasons, I don't want all the records in the table row to be synchronized since other users records will be there as well.

I have read about using filters in sqlite-sync but I didn't see anything that can prevent a user from manipulating the filter and synchronizing other user records instead.

What is the best method to use for the synchronization of just the user record only in a secure way (using authenticated user id)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a hard-to-guess random text string for your subscriberId. A `CHAR(10)` string that's Base64 encoded can carry 50 bits of randomness. That's fairly hard to guess.

When a user authenticates (logs in) pass the subscriberId to your mobile app.

When you create a new user account, use a high-quality random number generator to make her a new subscriberId.

Don't allow data lookup from your mobile app by a user serial number, only by subscriberId.

If your server gets a request for a nonexistent subscriberId, somebody is trying to guess valid values. Disconnect that person.